# ios 7.0 ruby on rails database on remote server

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am developing my first iOS (using 7.0) app. i want to send and retrieve data from a database on a remote server. The remote server is hosted by my web hosting company. they use LAMP stack. How can I use Ruby on Rails to add and retrieve data from the remote database? is there any book/website/tutorial that gives a clear solution?

Comment: do u have the access in that database?

Answer (score 0):

**API**

Although I've yet to design this myself, I know that RoR apps tie into iOS through an [API](http://railscasts.com/episodes/350-rest-api-versioning). If you wish to transfer data to/from your rails app, you'll be best making an authenticated API, like this:

```
#config/routes.rb
namespace :api do
   resources :controller
end

#app/controllers/api/your_controller.rb
module Api
   class YourController < ApplicationController
      respond_to :json

      def xxx
      end
   end
end
```

This is a *very* basic representation of what you'll have to do to create a JSON-powered "api" for a Rails app, which you'll be able to use to communicate with your database.

Some caveats to this include that you'll need to [authenticate](http://railscasts.com/episodes/352-securing-an-api) any request:

[image]

--

There's a good technical overview [here](http://www.slideshare.net/maximeguilbot/rails-as-ios-application-backend):

[image]

Comment: Rich, thanks for the high level over view, As I have never used ruby on rails/json/restful apis,  I am looking for a detailed answer, hopefully step by step. Also, I am noticing that the folks on the internet are using php as a way to communicate with the remote server. so, the question then arises why use ruby on rails at all?

Comment: Ruby on Rails / PHP is a choice of design. They work in the same way (provide mid-level programming functionality), so the question should really be based on which [`framework`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_application_frameworks) you're most eager to use.

Comment: Rails, for me, is the preferred choice for several reasons. 1 - it's highly extensible (LOADS of third party dependencies. 2. - its community is unparalleled. 3. - its s elegant & simple to develop - it makes programming *fun*

Comment: You won't get many detailed step-by-step answers on this topic. SO is mainly for specific questions (IE I have method `x` and need to return value `y`). I wanted to give you the bottom-line, which is that you'll need to use a REST API to handle the job properly

Comment: I agree with @RichPeck - don't go PHP if you can avoid it. Rails is a much nicer language to work with and the newer generation of programmers are using it much more than PHP. PHP is IMO not only messier but harder to find people that want to work with it. Secondly unfortunately this isn't a place to find hand written tutorials on how to write your full API on demand. There are plenty of documentation and tutorials out there though you can look for that on

Comment: I agree, I did try to search for tutorials/documentation on the web and developer.apple.com. there are books on objective c/ios and then there are books on ruby. but, i haven't been able to find a book that clearly bridges the two together. there are fragments on the internet but not enough clear instructions. to "manujmv", yes i do have access to the database on the remote server.